# Facebook Like box does not work with Google Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-likebox

The Facebook Like box for my webpage does not show with Google Chrome, but shows with IE (not sure about others like firefox). I am using the IFrame code supplied by Facebook. I've tried adding http:// to the Facebook iFrame code... I checked my FB settings (age is 13+, no geographic restrictions) I have read on here that others have had a similar problem, but no answer. I also have the same problem with my other websites that have the like box embedded. Is this a Facebook or Google error? Or did I miss something? Thanks!
http://birdofthehand.com/BotHF_News.htm 
(the like box should be under the text that reads "the farm stand is closed")

Comment: code -    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBirdOfTheHandFarm&width=650&height=590&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&header=true&stream=true&show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:650px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: I just tried your site out in IE and Chrome and it seems to work exactly the same in both browsers - seems to be working.

Comment: @Annabel Thanks, but I still can't see it on my Chrome browser. Could there be a Chrome setting I missed or Windows 8.1 update interference?

Comment: I don't know. Can you describe what happens to your Like box in Chrome: does it display properly? what happens when you click on it?

Comment: @Annabel Nothing shows. The space where the like box should be is just blank. I can highlight the area where it should be, but nothing happens when clicked. Thanks.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. but the Chrome hided the container div too. I thins where Chrome cannot load the iframe page - He's hide it. I opened the Developer tools, he added _style="display: none !important;"_ to the iframe & new block in style: _#socialbookmarks, #socialbookmarks, #socialbottom, #socialboxouter, #socialbuttons, #socialconnect, #socialcontainer, #socialcounterwidget, #socialfb, #socialfacebook, #socialfeedbackbar, #socialfloor, #socialfollow, #socialfooter, #socialgrid, #socialheader, #socialicons, #socialiconsbox, #socialiconscontainer, #socialinner {
display: none;
}_

Answer (score 2):

I've found out that it was my recent update of Avast virus scanner that caused the problem. I said yes to installation of an online scanner.
I checked Google Chromes extension, deleted this extension, and now the like box is loading again.
Erling
Denmark

Comment: Thank you! The Google Chrome Avast Extension settings were set to block social media under the advanced settings (Under Do Not Track). I unchecked it and now I can still use Avast and see my Facebook Social Media Plug-ins on websites. Thanks for your help! (It would be nice if Avast mentioned that problem somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the DISCONNECT Chrome extension that was causing the problem.

So anyway, usually it's an extension causing this issue!